# Linear algebra. Question about symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if

$(Au)\cdot v = u\cdot (Av)$ for every $u$ and $v$

then $A$ is symmetric.

I tried using a $2\times2$, but didn't help.

Comment: I'm assuming that's left and right matrix multiplication?

Comment: HINT: consider $u,v$ elements of the canonical basis. Waht is $Ae_i \cdot e_j$?

Comment: u and v are eigenvectors.

Comment: Your original question said "(Au).v = u.(Av)."  Does the adjoint operator $A^*$ that was edited in by another user match your original intention?

Comment: The original question had $(Au).v=u.(Av)$.  The comments clarify that this is to be assumed for $u$ and $v$ eigenvectors.  Clearly, then, the condition holds if and only if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are equal, for example $A$ could be any upper triangular matrix with $1$'s down the diagonal.  And clearly it is not the case that all such matrices are symmetric.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note: When I wrote my answer, the problem was to prove that if $(Au)\cdot v=u\cdot(Av)$ for every $u$ and $v$, then $A$ is symmetric.

Let $u=e_i$ and $v=e_j$ be standard basis vectors, and write $A=(a_{ij})$. Then $Au$ is the $i$-th column of $A$, and $(Au)\cdot v$ is the $j$-th entry of that column, $a_{ji}$. Similarly, $Av$ is the $j$-th column of $A$, and $u\cdot(Av)=a_{ij}$. Therefore we have $a_{ji}=a_{ij}$, so $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: According to the OP, the assumption applies only when $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors of $A$, so this argument won't work.

Comment: For the record, the downvote was not from me.

Answer (score -1):

Look at $ u,v$ being standard unit vectors $e_i, e_j$. Then, what are the quantities in question?